# Login Asp.net que redireciona para página PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

Queria saber se é possível fazer um login em Asp.net que redireciona para uma página em PHP. Se possível qual a melhor forma de verificar o usuário logado? Session? Cookie?

Comment: Ja pensou em utilizar o JWT ?

Comment: Não pensei... Na verdade preciso fazer um projeto para meu curso (CTI), e tenho que usar as duas linguagens em um projeto só (PHP e Asp.net C#) daí queria fazer só o login em Asp.net mas algo bem simples... aí pensei em usar Session ou Cookie ou outra forma, mas não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer

Comment: Só o login seria em Asp.net daí iria redirecionar para uma página em PHP, mas tenho que verificar o usuário logado em uma Session por exemplo, mas seria de uma linguagem pra outra...

Comment: por isso te dei uma solução que seria o jwt aonde você passa tudo por token